# Detect user mouse click in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

I am trying to make a game in matlab where the user selects a shape and that shape translates and scales down a screen. The user then has to click on the shape and a point is added to their score.  I was wondering how to make the program detect the users mouse click on the shape but end the program if they click on white space.

Comment: "I am trying to make a game in matlab" ...why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go along these lines. The following code basically uses:

- [`fill`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) to draw a polygonal shape;
- [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) to get cursor position;
- [`inpolygon`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) to check if that position is inside the polygon.

Code:

```
xv = [ -3 3 3 -3]; %// x coords of polygon vertices. Arbitrary number
yv = [-5 -5 7 7]; %// y coords of polygon vertices. Same number as for x
fill(xv,yv,'b') %// draw polygon
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
[xp, yp] = ginput(1); %// get point coordinates
inside = inpolygon(xp,yp,xv,yv); %// is it inside?
if inside
    %// it's inside. Do something accordingly
else
    %// it's outside. Do something else
end
```